# Is a DNS server (like Bind9) usefull with a LAMP stack

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, bind, web-hosting

The question might seem naive, I know what a DNS server is, but as far as I know, in most cases, you don't need a DNS server as you (or the computer/server) can request an external DNS when needed. And yet, Ubuntu server includes Bind9 by default.

For instance, is there any advantage not getting rid of it in a typical LAMP stack? Is there any caching for reverse or something? Otherwise, I don't see any reason I shouldn't:

```
apt-get purge bind9 bind9-doc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you explictly select it with the package group "DNS server", `bind` doesn't get installed by default.

If it is installed and you don't need it (which is the case for the vast majority of installations), you can indeed safely purge the package.

Answer (score -2):

if you have your own dns server, you can:

- use local domains for your server farm (ie. domain.loc) instead of private ips
- setup local cache
- handle outage of dns of your provider

All of this are usefull but need configuration and understanding what are you doing. If you don't have time or will to learn it, just uninstall it and use dns of your provider.